# How to create arguments from a message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to make a music bot for my discord server, I have it set to play the music, but I can't figure out how to make it play a link that the user inputs

```
client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith("^play")) {
    let channel = client.channels.get('496722898858278912');
    const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
    const streamOptions = {
      seek: 0,
      volume: 1
    };
    const broadcast = client.createVoiceBroadcast();

    channel.join()
      .then(connection => {
        const stream = ytdl(('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XAWgeLF9EVQ'), {filter: 'audioonly'});
        broadcast.playStream(stream);
        const dispatcher = connection.playBroadcast(broadcast);
      });
  }
});
```

The link in the code would be replaced with the user submitted link.

Comment: const stream = ytdl((message.content.replace("^play", ""), { filter : 'audioonly' }); This will remove ^play, so there should be only the link. But you must check if it's a link, if it's a youtube video link and if the video exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create arguments, you can split the content of the message using `' '` as separator, the arguments are the elements of that array except for the first (that's the command):

```
// message.content: "^play https://youtube.com/blablabla other arguments"
let args = message.content.split(' '); // ["^play", "https://youtube.com/blablabla", "other", "arguments"]: the string got splitted into different parts
args.shift(); // remove the first element (the command)
// you can do all your stuff, when you need the link you find it in args[0]
const stream = ytdl((args[0]), { filter : 'audioonly' });
```

Please note that the first argument is not granted to be a valid youtube link, so check it or prepare your code to handle an invalid argument.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried many different ways to do this, but yours is the only one that completely worked!

Comment: Happy to hear that :)